# python file parse query

Tags: parsing

I am trying to parse a text file so that out of three columns 2nd column (High) and 3rd column (Low) values goes to two different empty strings. But unfortunately i cannot get it work eventhough i have tried innumerable number of times. My text file looks like this

```
Boston July Temperatures
-------------------------

Day High Low
------------

1 91 70
2 84 69
3 86 68
4 84 68
5 83 70
6 80 68
7 86 73
8 89 71
9 84 67
10 83 65
```

And here is my code that i have tried so far.

```
low_Temp=[]
high_Temp=[]
inFile = open('julyTemps.txt')
for line in inFile.readlines():
    fields = line.strip(' ')
    if len(fields) < 3 or not fields[0].isdigit():
        pass
    else:
        low_Temp.append(fields[2])
        high_Temp.append(fields[1])
print low_Temp
print high_Temp
```

Finally my goal is calculate the difference between these values and plot the difference across days. i think i can do that part if i can figure out why i am not getting the correct values in the empty vectors.

Could somebody explain me what i was doing wrong. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure you open your file in universal mode, to account for different line endings:

```
 inFile = open('julyTemps.txt', 'rU') # read universal
```

Your general approach then looks okay.  It's nicer to iterate through the file object rather than use readlines, though:

```
for line in inFile:
    line = line.strip() # remove newline characters
    fields = line.split(' ')

    if len(fields) == 3:
         _, high, low = fields
         high_Temp.append(float(high))
         low_Temp.append(float(low))
```

What is the exact problem you're getting with your current approach (or the one I posted above)?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am basically getting two strings that look like this...I still don't get why i am getting these...low_Temp = ['9', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
high_Temp = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1']